# Adicionar variáveis a colunas (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, node.js

Eu tenho uma pergunta, é possivel adicionar variáveis numa coluna?

**Codigo Test**

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO sometable (someparam) VALUES (varToParam)";
con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("test");
});
```

**Erro**

```
Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'varToParam' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Qual é o nome da(s) variável(eis) e qual o nome(s) da(s) coluna(s)?

Comment: coluna `someparam` e a variavel como está exemplificado no codigo "varToParam"

Comment: Ok, então testa assim: `var sql = "INSERT INTO sometable (someparam) VALUES (" + varToParam + ")";`

Comment: Já funcionou obrigado @Sergio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se `varToParam` é uma variável com um valor lá dentro que queres inserir dentro da string da query, então tens de concatenar esse valor.

Podes usar o `+` que é o operador de concatenação ou template strings.

**Concatenando:**

```
var varToParam = 4862349862435;
var sql = "INSERT INTO sometable (someparam) VALUES (" + varToParam + ")";
// vai dar: INSERT INTO sometable (someparam) VALUES (4862349862435)
```

**Com template string:**

```
var varToParam = 4862349862435;
var sql = `INSERT INTO sometable (someparam) VALUES (${varToParam})`;
// vai dar: INSERT INTO sometable (someparam) VALUES (4862349862435)
```

---

Tem cuidado para tratar sempre os dados antes de inserir na base de dados. Essa biblioteca tem uma função para isso `mysql.escape` que pode ser usada assim:

```
var varToParam = 4862349862435;
varToParam = mysql.escape(varToParam);
var sql = "INSERT INTO sometable (someparam) VALUES (" + varToParam + ")";
```

Ou então assim, com a API da biblioteca para isso:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO sometable (someparam) VALUES (??)";
con.query(sql, [varToParam], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("test");
});
```